# Submit dropzone form from another form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I have two forms on my page, one where users can upload images and the other where they can rename the files. The first one looks like this

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => Request::url(), 'class'=>'dropzone', 
            'id' =>"my-awesome-dropzone", 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true)) }}  
{{ Form::close()}}
```

And the second

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => Request::url())) }}
{{ Form::text('name', null, array('id' => 'name', 'placeholder' => 'Name')) }}
{{ Form::submit('Upload', array('name' => 'upload-file')) }}
```

Is it possible to use this submit to upload the files from the other form?

```
{{ Form::close() }}
```

This is the js. I got no errors from php nor from js/jquery, the files are simply not uploading and I don't know where to look for errors or what I'm doing wrong. Is there another way? Some help will be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function() {
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element

    thumbnailWidth: 150,
    thumbnailHeight: 150,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFiles: 10,
    // The setting up of the dropzone
    init: function() {
        var myDropzone = this;

        // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
        document.querySelector("input[name=upload-file]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        });
        this.on("addedfile", function(file) { $( "#form-width" ).show( "slow" );
        $( "#form-rename" ).show( "slow" );});

        // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
        // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
        this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
            // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
            // Hide the success button or the complete form.
        });
        this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
            // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
            // Redirect user or notify of success.
        });
        this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
            // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
            // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
        });
    }

};
});
```